# Can I run 3 uwsgi service using different port

Tags: python-3.x, django, uwsgi, django-q

I have 3 python django application on same server. And I want to run each service using different port.

ex)
80     for end user
8001   for service provider
8002   for service operator

But I have no idea how can I do this.

Now, one uwsgi service is running using systemctl.

This is my uwsgi.service.

```
# uwsgi.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /var/run/uwsgi; chown root:ubuntu 
/var/run/uwsgi; chmod g+w /var/run/uwsgi;'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source /var/www/html/remosys/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini /var/www/html/remosys/uwsgi.ini'
#Restart=always
Restart=on-failure
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And uwsgi.ini is the following.

```
[uwsgi]
uid = ubuntu
gid = ubuntu

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir = /var/www/html/remosys/remoshin

# Django's wsgi file
module = remoshin.wsgi

# the virtualenv (full path)
home = /var/www/html/remosys


# process-related settings
# master
master = true

# maximum number of worker processes
processes = 2

threads = 1

# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/master.sock

pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi/master.pid

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket = 666

# clear environment on exit
vacuum = true

thunder-lock = true

max-requests = 6000
max-requests-delta = 300

# log
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
deamonize = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-@(exec://date +%Y-%m-%d).log
log-reopen = true
```

And my nginx setting is the following.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # for a file socket
    server unix:///var/run/uwsgi/master.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    server_name localhost
    charset     utf-8;

    location /clinic {
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        alias /home/ubuntu/public_html/clinic;
    }
    # max upload size
    # Django media
    location /static {
        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        alias /home/ubuntu/remosys/remoshin/apiv1/static;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        include     /var/www/html/remosys/uwsgi_params;
}
```

}

I want to know how can I make settings in order to launch some uwsgi service and how to setting nginx config file.

Would you give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uwsgi_p1.ini for my_project1

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/my_workplace/my_project1
module = my_project1.wsgi
virtualenv = /root/my_workplace/virtual/my_project1
processes = 2
socket = 127.0.0.1:10001    # **pay attention to this port**
vacuum = true
master = true
```

nginx_p1.conf for my_project1

```
server {
listen      8888;  #  use different server_name or listenport
charset     utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;

server_name project1.mydomain.com;  #  use different server_name or listenport

location / {
    uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:10001;   #  pay attention to here
    include     uwsgi_params;
}
}
```

==============================

uwsgi_p2.ini for my_project2

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/my_workplace/my_project2
module = my_project2.wsgi
virtualenv = /root/my_workplace/virtual/project2
processes = 2
socket = 127.0.0.1:10002
vacuum = true
master = true
```

nginx_p2.conf for my_project2

```
server {
listen      8889;
charset     utf-8;
client_max_body_size 75M;

server_name project2.mydomain.com;  

location / {
    uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:10002;   
    include     uwsgi_params;
}
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I have more one question. How do you launch uwsgi service? I tried 'sudo systemctl uwsgi --ini uwsgi_1.ini', and 'sudo systemctl uwsgi --ini uwsgi_2.ini'. But I got duplicate error message when I try to launch second command.

Comment: I use  [supervisor](http://www.supervisord.org/). It's a common way to admin django-uwsgi process.

Comment: @KazzzStudio Don't use supervisor. We used to use supervisor because systemd was not available at the time. Now that all major distributions use systemd there's no need to use supervisor (systemd is already installed and it's more robust, and is equally easy to configure). The only downside is it has worse documentation, but since you have already managed to work with it, you don't need to go with the legacy solution.

Comment: @KazzzStudio You just need to create `uwsgi1.service` and `uwsgi2.service` (but better use a more descriptive qualifier than `1` and `2`).

Comment: where does the number 127.0.0.1 come from?