# How to configure NGINX & uwsgi to support several TLDs with one app

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config

I'm using Python & uwsgi & NGINX configuration and I have one application and several TLDs for my domain, like:

mydomain.com

blog.mydomain.com

news.mydomain.com

My current NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/app/mydomain/mydomain.sock;
    }
}
```

Desired behavior:

I want to define the additional endpoint '/blog_tld' in my application and match this endpoint with domain name blog.mydomain.com.

When the user opens blog.mydomain.com he/she should see the content from mydomain.com/blog_tld, but the address in the browser should remain as blog.mydomain.com

I don't want to create separate application & uwsgi service for each TLD. I want to use one application and one uwsgi service, but show different content for different TLDs.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853945/can-i-run-3-uwsgi-service-using-different-port

Comment: Yes, we can use two different uwsgi apps for different TLD, but the question was about how to do this with only one app.

Answer (score 0):

something like that

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_...
    ...

    server_name blog.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>/blog_tld
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_...
    ...

    server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this way also, but nginx can't accept configuration with: 
`uwsgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>/blog_tld`

Comment: <port> replace this with the port number (should be 9000 or other). if stil not working replace the line with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>/blog_tld;` (or 9000)